# How to sort an array of objects in jquery dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, sorting

I know that when your sorting two objects, object a and object b, the sort method works,

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    var a1= a.name, b1= b.name;
    if(a1== b1) return 0;
    return a1> b1? 1: -1;
});
```

however i echoed a list of stdclass objects from my server, a long list, since i am hoping to categorize them by their object attributes.
If my list of  data looks like this,

```
      array( 
           [7] => stdClass Object
            (
           [id] => 3
           [title] => Electrition
           [img] => 
           [description] => 
           [school] => 
           [location] => 1
           [url] => 
           [tablename] => 3
           [votes] => 0
           [name] => John Doe
           [NumJobsdone] => 4
               )

             [8] => stdClass Object
           (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Electrition
            [img] => 
            [description] => 
            [school] => 
            [location] => 1
            [url] => 
            [tablename] => 2
            [votes] => 0
            [name] => Tico Marinez
            [NumJobsdone] => 6
            )

            [9] => stdClass Object
            (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Engineer
            [img] => 
            [description] => 
            [school] => 
            [location] => 1
            [tablename] => 2
            [votes] => 0
            [name] => Jerry Smity
            [NumJobsdone] => 6
           )

         [10] => stdClass Object
           (
           [id] => 2
           [title] => Engineer
           [img] => 
           [description] => 
           [school] => 
           [location] => 1
           [url] => 
           [tablename] => 2
           [votes] => 0
            [name] => Laura Bastian
           [NumJobsdone] => 6
             )
            )
```

and im trying to sort them by the title attibute, and i've been iterating through the list using the $.each method but how would one sort through multiple objects dynamically using jquery?

Comment: You can use  `json_encode ` to create a useable javascript equiv.

Comment: this is the print_r data, i normally json_encode it and echo it so that my AJAX function can get the data, the only issue is figuring out how to not only iterate through the data but to also organize it by object attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `return a.title > b.title` within `.sort()` compare function

```js
var arr = [{
  "title": "Electrician"
}, {
  "title": "Engineer"
}, {
  "title": "Architect"
}];

var res = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.title > b.title
});

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```